# how to add Old data to select inputs inform

Tags: laravel

this code is ok with text inputs

```
<input value="{{ old('YOM') }}" id="YOM" class="form-control" type="year" name="YOM" id="">
```

but want add old data to select tag s and also radio buttons

```
<select id="condition" name="condition"  class=" form-control" >
    <option value="" >Select Condition</option>
    <option value="Brand New"  >Brand New</option>
    <option value="Recondition" >Recondition</option>
    <option value="Used" >Used</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="SaleOrRent" value="Sell">Sell <span></span>    
<input type="checkbox" name="SaleOrRent" value="Rent">Rent
<input type="checkbox" name="SaleOrRent" value="Sell or Rent">Sell or Rent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this.

```php
<select id="condition" name="condition"  class=" form-control" >
    <option value="" >Select Condition</option>
    <option value="Brand New" {{ old('condition') === 'Brand New' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Brand New</option>
    <option value="Recondition" {{ old('condition') === 'Recondition' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Recondition</option>
    <option value="Used" {{ old('condition') === 'Used' ? 'selected' : '' }} >Used</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="SaleOrRent" value="Sell" {{ old('SaleOrRent') === 'Sell' ? 'checked' : '' }} >Sell <span></span>    
<input type="checkbox" name="SaleOrRent" value="Rent" {{ old('SaleOrRent') === 'Rent' ? 'checked' : '' }} >Rent
<input type="checkbox" name="SaleOrRent" value="Sell or Rent" {{ old('SaleOrRent') === 'Sell or Rent' ? 'checked' : '' }} >Sell or Rent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="{{old('condition'}}" >Select Condition</option>
```

and for the radio:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="SaleOrRent" value="{{old('saleOrRent)}}">Sell <span></span>
```